# Get all calls to specific function in source file and generate other files (using C, C++ preprocessor or scripts)

Tags: c++, c, preprocessor

I have a program like below:

```
// test.c
#include <stdio.h>

#define LOG     printf
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    LOG("Hello, my name %s, my age %d\n", "John", 30);
    LOG("I have wife and %d kids\n", 2);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to create a log file which contains all texts like:

```
// message.txt
LINE: "Hello, my name %s, my age %d\n"
LINE: "I have wife and %d kids\n"
```

Is it possible to do it using C's **preprocessor**, **make**, or even a **script**?

---

Edited:

Let's say I have a program that prints those messages in English already, I have source code for sure, now I want to support French then:
I need to get all messages that developers put into their program and create a `message.txt` which contains all texts, replace each message in original program with an identify number which maps each message in `message.txt`. I want to do it programmatically not manually.

Comment: I'm a little unsure what you're actually asking... Do you just want to search all source file for where `LOG` is used? Or do you actually want to *implement* a logging system?

Comment: So you're saying you want to log the raw format strings?  Why?

Comment: Don't know about preprocessor and Make but for sure it can be done with a script. Or you could write a `c` program  :-)

Comment: Let say I have a program that prints those message in English already, I have source code for sure, now I want to support French then I need to get all messages that developers putted into their program and create a **message.txt** which contains all texts; replace each message in original program with an identify number which maps with message in **message.txt**. I want to do it programmatic not manually.

Comment: @sdao: read about [internationalization and localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) and, at least on POSIX, consider using [gettext](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gettext.3.html) and friends.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is localization, read something about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization). If you're on a posix system you can use `gettext()` for that, see [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/gettext). If you're using Windows you can take a look at [GetText for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gettext.htm).

---

Nevertheless I wrote a little C++ program that generate the files you want, see code below.
You call it via `myProg filename logFunction` where `filename` is the source file you want to input and `logFunction` is for example `LOG`.

You will get a map file called `filename_map` and  a new source file `filename_new`. The new source file will contain a new macro `LOG` and a function `readLocaleStrings()` which will read all the strings at program start from the `filename_map` file. The new macro `LOG` will use the right strings automatically then.

---

In your example you would call it by `myProg test.c LOG` and would get:

**`test_map.txt`:**

```
7: "Hello, my name %s, my age %d\n"
8: "I have wife and %d kids\n"
```

and a **`test_new.c`**:

```
// test.c
#include <stdio.h>

#define LOG(filename,line,...)   printf(localeStrings.strings[localeStrings.lastIdx++], __VA_ARGS__)

/* Beginning: Generated code for localization */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
   size_t  count;
   size_t  lastIdx;
   char ** strings;
} stringArray_t;

stringArray_t localeStrings = { 0, 0, NULL };

int readLocaleStrings (const char * const filename)
{
   FILE * file = NULL;
   char * line = NULL;
   char * str = NULL;
   size_t len = 0;
   ssize_t read;

   file = fopen(filename, "r");
   if (file == NULL)
   {
      return -1;
   }

   localeStrings.strings = malloc (sizeof (char *));
   localeStrings.count = 0;

   while (-1 != (read = getline(&line, &len, file)))
   {
      size_t curIdx = localeStrings.count++;
      localeStrings.strings = realloc(localeStrings.strings, localeStrings.count * sizeof (char *));

      str = strstr(line, "\"");
      localeStrings.strings[curIdx] = malloc(sizeof (char) * (size_t)(1 + read));
      strcpy (localeStrings.strings[curIdx], str);
   }

   fclose(file);
   if (line)
   {
      free(line);
   }

   return 0;
}

void freeLocaleStrings()
{
   size_t idx;
   for (idx = 0; idx < localeStrings.count; ++idx)
   {
      free(localeStrings.strings[idx]);
   }
   free(localeStrings.strings);
}
/* End: Generated code for localization */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
   readLocaleStrings("test_map.txt");
   LOG("test_map.txt", "7", "John", 30);
   LOG("test_map.txt", "8", 2);
   freeLocaleStrings();
   return 0;
}
```

---

**C++ program:**

The C++ program has limitation, it will just find `LOG("` if you want also to find `LOG` with spaces anywhere like: `LOG ("` you have to change that code. Moreover there are cases such as multiple lines messages, messages that had been commented out etc. You have to extend the code for your requirements then. Also there is no great argument parse handling or error checking. Further for the writing of the helper code it is needed to find the main function. But for your given input file it works perfectly and should just point you in the right direction. To extend it more easy and make it more flexible using a regex library would be wise.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

/* Function definition is under main function */
const char * getNextHelperFunctionLine();

std::string getExtension (const std::string filename)
{
   /* get dot of e.g. foo.c */
   size_t posDot = filename.rfind('.');

   /* extract extension */
   std::string extension;
   if (std::string::npos != posDot)
   {
      /* extension found */
      extension = filename.substr(posDot);
   }

   return extension;
}

std::string getFilename (const std::string filename)
{
   /* get dot of e.g. foo.c */
   size_t posDot = filename.rfind('.');

   /* extract filename */
   std::string name = filename;
   if (std::string::npos != posDot)
   {
      name  = name.substr(0, posDot);
   }

   return name;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
   if (argc < 3)
   {
      std::cerr << "Usage: "
                << "   " << argv[0] << " filename logFunction"
                << std::endl;

      return 0;
   }
   std::string infileName (argv[1]);

   /* extract filename and extension */
   std::string filename  = getFilename(infileName);
   std::string extension = getExtension(infileName);;

   /* names for generated files */
   std::string mapfileName = filename + "_map.txt";
   std::string mappedfileName = filename + "_new" + extension;

   /* open streams for input and output */
   std::ifstream infile(infileName.c_str());
   std::ofstream fileMap(mapfileName.c_str());
   std::ofstream fileMapped(mappedfileName.c_str());

   /* string for log function e.g. "LOG(" */
   std::string logFun = std::string(argv[2]);
   std::string logFunOpen = logFun + "(\"";

   std::string lineRead;
   size_t lineNr = 1;

   size_t mainParanthesis = 0;
   bool   mainReturnFound = false;

   /* Loop through whole input file */
   while (std::getline(infile, lineRead))
   {
      /* position of log function opening e.g. "LOG(" */
      size_t posLogOpen = lineRead.find(logFunOpen);

      /* opening found? */
      bool foundOpen  = std::string::npos != posLogOpen;
      if (foundOpen)
      {
         bool foundClose = false;
         /* position of the string beginning */
         size_t posLogStringBeg = posLogOpen + logFunOpen.length();
         size_t posLogClose = posLogStringBeg;
         /* find closing of the log function e.g. "LOG(...)" */
         while (!foundClose)
         {
            /* search for '"' and skip these if they are in the string */
            posLogClose = lineRead.find("\"", posLogClose + 1);
            if (std::string::npos != posLogClose)
            {
               foundClose = (0 != lineRead.compare(posLogClose - 1, 1, "\\"));
            }
         }

         /* closing found write map file and new source file */
         if (foundClose)
         {
            size_t len = posLogClose - posLogStringBeg;

            fileMap << lineNr << ": \""
                    << lineRead.substr(posLogStringBeg, len) << "\""
                    << std::endl;

            fileMapped << lineRead.substr(0, posLogStringBeg - 1)
                       << '"' << mapfileName << "\", "
                       << '"' << lineNr
                       << lineRead.substr(posLogClose)
                       << std::endl;
         }
      }
      /* not a log function write normal code */
      else
      {
         if (   std::string::npos != lineRead.find("#define")
             && std::string::npos != lineRead.find(logFun))
         {
            /* log functions needs to be changed */
            fileMapped << "#define "
                       << logFun << "(filename,line,...)   "
                       << "printf(localeStrings.strings[localeStrings.lastIdx++], __VA_ARGS__)" << std::endl;
         }
         else if (   0 == mainParanthesis
             && std::string::npos != lineRead.find(" main")
             && std::string::npos != lineRead.find("(")
             && std::string::npos != lineRead.find(")"))
         {
            /* found main function write all helper functions in front of it */
            const char * helperLine;
            while ((helperLine = getNextHelperFunctionLine()))
            {
               fileMapped << helperLine << std::endl;
            }

            /* write main function part */
            fileMapped << lineRead << std::endl;

            /* is there an opening parenthesis? */
            if (std::string::npos != lineRead.find("{"))
            {
               ++mainParanthesis;
               fileMapped << "   readLocaleStrings(\"" << mapfileName << "\");" << std::endl;
            }
         }
         else
         {
            /* in main function write first part */
            if (std::string::npos != lineRead.find("{"))
            {
               /* write opening */
               fileMapped << lineRead << std::endl;

               if (0 == mainParanthesis)
               {
                  fileMapped << "   readLocaleStrings(\"" << mapfileName << "\");" << std::endl;
               }
               ++mainParanthesis;
            }
            /* return statement? */
            else if (   1 == mainParanthesis
                     && std::string::npos != lineRead.find("return"))
            {
               mainReturnFound = true;
               fileMapped << "   freeLocaleStrings();" << std::endl;

               /* write return */
               fileMapped << lineRead << std::endl;
            }
            else if (   1 == mainParanthesis
                     && std::string::npos != lineRead.find("}"))
            {
               --mainParanthesis;
               if (!mainReturnFound)
               {
                  fileMapped << "   freeLocaleStrings();" << std::endl;
               }

               /* write closing */
               fileMapped << lineRead << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
               /* write other code */
               fileMapped << lineRead << std::endl;
            }
         }
      }
      ++lineNr;
   }

   return 0;
}

const char * getNextHelperFunctionLine()
{
   static size_t idx = 0;
   static const char * helperFunLines[] =
   {
      "",
      "/* Beginning: Generated code for localization */",
      "#include <stdlib.h>",
      "#include <string.h>",
      "",
      "typedef struct {",
      "   size_t  count;",
      "   size_t  lastIdx;",
      "   char ** strings;",
      "} stringArray_t;",
      "",
      "stringArray_t localeStrings = { 0, 0, NULL };",
      "",
      "int readLocaleStrings (const char * const filename)",
      "{",
      "   FILE * file = NULL;",
      "   char * line = NULL;",
      "   char * str = NULL;",
      "   size_t len = 0;",
      "   ssize_t read;",
      "",
      "   file = fopen(filename, \"r\");",
      "   if (file == NULL)",
      "   {",
      "      return -1;",
      "   }",
      "",
      "   localeStrings.strings = malloc (sizeof (char *));",
      "   localeStrings.count = 0;",
      "",
      "   while (-1 != (read = getline(&line, &len, file)))",
      "   {",
      "      size_t curIdx = localeStrings.count++;",
      "      localeStrings.strings = realloc(localeStrings.strings, localeStrings.count * sizeof (char *));",
      "",
      "      str = strstr(line, \"\\\"\");",
      "      localeStrings.strings[curIdx] = malloc(sizeof (char) * (size_t)(1 + read));",
      "      strcpy (localeStrings.strings[curIdx], str);",
      "   }",
      "",
      "   fclose(file);",
      "   if (line)",
      "   {",
      "      free(line);",
      "   }",
      "",
      "   return 0;",
      "}",
      "",
      "void freeLocaleStrings()",
      "{",
      "   size_t idx;",
      "   for (idx = 0; idx < localeStrings.count; ++idx)",
      "   {",
      "      free(localeStrings.strings[idx]);",
      "   }",
      "   free(localeStrings.strings);",
      "}",
      "/* End: Generated code for localization */",
      ""
   };

   if (idx < (sizeof (helperFunLines) / sizeof (helperFunLines[0])))
   {
      return helperFunLines[idx++];
   }
   else
   {
      return nullptr; /* use NULL if compiler doesn't support nullptr */
   }
}
```

Comment: Multi-statement macro bodies are really nothing I recommend. The last one, with the `do ... while(0)` around is better. There are other solutions, including using the macro to pass arguments to a single function that does the logging (which I rather recommend). But it's still unclear if this is what the OP really is asking about.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Yeah you're right, I changed the others too.

Comment: Hello @AndreKampling, thanks, I will check. The importance is how to deal with error cases such as multiple lines messages, messages had been commented out, messages have special escape characters (Ex: \"), etc.

Comment: @sdao: Yes right for that you have to extend the C++ program to meet the requirements. My solution should just point in the right direction and work for a simple case first. By the way special characters like `"` are no problems. The last `"` will be used as end. But multiple lines will be a problem...

Comment: @sdao: Using regex libraries would made it very easy to match a pattern to use it in more complex examples.